# Empty parameter on a MVC 4 ApiController action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am passing a Javascript array of a collection of strings to a post action on my apicontroller, there is a data being sent ( i know this via fiddler ) but it doesn't seem to actually get to the controller action when i am debugging the code. My code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: Just to clarify, the controller action is called but the List stuffsId has a count of zero when there is a list being passed to it**

Ajax/Javascript

```
my.sendStuffToController = function (stuffIds, completedHandler) {

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: my.stuffUrl,
            data: {
                stuffIds: stuffIds
            },
            success: function (data) {

                if (completedHandler !== undefined) {
                    completedHandler(stuffIds);
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

My ApiController Post Action

```
    // Post 
    public void PostAsync(List<string> stuffIds)
    {
        var clientProxy = this.proxyFactory.CreateClientProxy(Tokens.EndPoint);
        var clientChannel = clientProxy.GetClientChannel();

        try
        {
            clientChannel.DoStuffAsync(stuffIds);
        }
        finally
        {
            clientProxy.TryCloseAbortClientChannel();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataType` is used to specify the return type of the request.   `contentType` is what you should be using to tell the server what you are sending.

Comment: changing it from dataType to contentType didnt seem to do anything

Comment: @PhilipLoyer  Did you set the content type to application/json ?

Comment: So it turns out that was part of the problem, that was a key part though. 

So here is what I did to solve it in totality.

I changed

    public void PostAsync(List<string> stuffIds)

to

    public void PostAsync([FromBody] IEnumerable<string> stuffIds)

and in my javascript 

  data: {
                stuffIds: stuffIds
            }, 

to

  data: JSON.stringify(stuffIds),

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible (and most common) problems with passing arrays as post parameters from jQuery is described [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-post-1-4-1-is-appending-to-vars-when-posting-from-array-within-array).

Short version:

Add

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

before your jQuery ajax() function call, i.e.

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
my.sendStuffToController = function (stuffIds, completedHandler) {

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: my.stuffUrl,
            data: {
                stuffIds: stuffIds
            },
            success: function (data) {

                if (completedHandler !== undefined) {
                    completedHandler(stuffIds);
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Long version:

From some point in time jQuery started appending square brackets to variable name if the variable is array, i.e. in your case it will transmit 'stuffIds[]:value1 stuffIds[]:value2' etc. over the ajax call. ASP.NET MVC does not like that and refuses to accept such parameters. `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true` switches this jQuery 'feature' off.

Comment: That did remove the brackets, but i am still get a zero count when the apicontroller action fires.